# Drawing using asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there any way to draw a simple image like some lines with asp.net mvc?
Any component or tool?

Actually user wants to draw a simple map and save it to database. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think they warn against doing it in ASP.NET but we've used the graphics libraries to do it before. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y289054.aspx

Answer (score 0):

try to understand mvc first, its a framework on top of ASP.NET not a client side tool. You could try [HTML5 Canvas](http://diveintohtml5.info/canvas.html)